# Sorting coordinates from lowest to highest

Tags: python, sorting

I have the following coordinate data that needs to be sorted.

```
array =
[[ 1.72  2.4 ]
[ 2.6   4.  ]
[ 0.6   2.4 ]
[ 3.8   0.8 ]
[ 1.6   0.  ]
[ 1.64  0.8 ]
[ 3.4   2.4 ]
[ 0.92  0.8 ]
[ 4.    0.  ]
[ 2.2   4.  ]
[ 3.2   3.2 ]
[ 3.6   1.6 ]
[ 1.4   4.  ]
[ 2.4   0.  ]
[ 0.4   1.6 ]
[ 1.8   4.  ]
[ 0.8   0.  ]
[ 3.2   0.  ]
[ 2.32  1.6 ]
[ 2.36  0.8 ]
[ 2.72  3.2 ]
[ 0.    0.  ]
[ 1.16  2.4 ]
[ 0.8   3.2 ]
[ 1.68  1.6 ]
[ 1.    4.  ]
[ 2.84  2.4 ]
[ 1.04  1.6 ]
[ 2.24  3.2 ]
[ 2.28  2.4 ]
[ 0.2   0.8 ]
[ 1.76  3.2 ]
[ 3.08  0.8 ]
[ 3.    4.  ]
[ 2.96  1.6 ]
[ 1.28  3.2 ]]
```

The first element in each value of the list correspond to x value and the next element correspond to y value. The y value should be sorted first, from lowest to highest. After sorting the y values, the x values should be sorted from lowest to highest. I have written the following function to sort it:

```
def sort_mesh(array):
    return sorted(array,key=lambda l: [l[1], l[0]])
```

The problem is that at first it works but then there is a mistake

```
[array([ 0.,  0.]), array([ 0.8,  0. ]), array([ 1.6,  0. ]), array([ 2.4,  0. ]), array([ 3.2,  0. ]), array([ 4.,  0.]), array([ 0.2,  0.8]), array([ 0.92,  0.8 ]), array([ 1.64,  0.8 ]), array([ 2.36,  0.8 ]), array([ 3.08,  0.8 ]), array([ 3.8,  0.8]), array([ 0.4,  1.6]), array([ 1.04,  1.6 ]), array([ 1.68,  1.6 ]), array([ 2.32,  1.6 ]), array([ 2.96,  1.6 ]), array([ 3.6,  1.6]), array([ 0.6,  2.4]),!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! array([ 3.4,  2.4]), array([ 1.16,  2.4 ]), array([ 1.72,  2.4 ]), array([ 2.28,  2.4 ]), array([ 2.84,  2.4 ]), array([ 0.8,  3.2]), array([ 1.28,  3.2 ]), array([ 1.76,  3.2 ]), array([ 2.24,  3.2 ]), array([ 2.72,  3.2 ]), array([ 3.2,  3.2]), array([ 1.,  4.]), array([ 1.4,  4. ]), array([ 1.8,  4. ]), array([ 2.2,  4. ]), array([ 2.6,  4. ]), array([ 3.,  4.])]
```

I added some "!" expression marks in the returned array so you can see where to find the mistake.

I hope someone can help me.

Best Regards

Comment: I've just copy pasted your code and everything seems to work fine

Comment: But how is this possible? Do i have some mixup with object types?

Comment: That could explain it. I assume that your array is a `numpy.ndarray` (is it what you see when typing `type(array)`?) If so, what is the dtype of your array (`array.dtype`) and do all rows have the same dtype (`[a.dtype for a in array]`)?

Comment: before sorting the array is a numpy.ndarray. Every element in it is dtype('float64'). After sorting the array becomes a list but all elements in in are still dtype('float64').

Comment: weird !!! what version of python are you using? are you sure that `sorted` is the built-in function or did you somehow overwrite it`?

Comment: i use 2.7. I don't think i have overwritten anything. I will just write my own loop now. But thank you for your help :)

Comment: sorry I can't help more. I don't know what is going on.